# Check if specific player nearby in Minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way i can check for a specific player standing on a block or is nearby and command block, and have it run another command like `/setblock` so it can execute other command blocks? So like if a player presses a button, it checks if the player has a certain nametag, and if not it doesn't open any door. But if the player does have a certain name tag then it opens the doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use target selectors, and use `/execute` to make it happen.

```
/execute if entity @a[x=10,y=20,z=30,distance=..10] run setblock 1 2 3 redstone_block
```

This will detect any players within 10 blocks of XYZ (10, 20, 30), and if any are found, it sets a redstone block at a certain position, whether to run more commands, or to open an iron door.

And to detect the name, use the `name` argument.

```
/execute if entity @a[name=ExpertCoder14] run ...
```

Combine these all together and you get:

```
/execute if entity @a[x=10,y=20,z=30,distance=0..5,name=ExpertCoder14] run setblock 1 2 3 redstone_block
```

Learn more about these commands and mechanics on the Minecraft Wiki:

- [Target selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors)
- [The `/execute` Command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute)